# How to Label Field With Multiple Selected Values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, sql, labeling

I have a shape named "Subdistrict" and it shown on Attribut Table like this :

**No | subd  | village 

1  | town1 | v1 

2  | town1 | v2 

3  | town1 | v3 

4  | town2 | v4 

5  | town2 | v5 

6  | town2 | v6 

7  | town3 | v7 

8  | town3 | v8 

9  | town3 | v9**

I want to select **only town1 and town3, and only v1, v3, v7, v8** 

I've select define classes each class differentley and use SQL Querry to select only Village :v1,v3,v7,v8 to shown on label, but it's not working.

this is my SQL querry code :

```
subd= 'town1' AND 'town3' AND village='v1' AND 'v3' AND 'v7' AND 'v8'
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: This statement cannot produce a selection as no subd can be 'town1' and also 'town2'. Boolean logic is that it must be OR so: subd = 'town1' or subd = 'town2'. The use of brackets in this case is advisable.

Comment: Yes, it has to use brackets, Already Solved. Thanks

Comment: Please do not put "SOLVED" in your Question title - the way to indicate that you have a solution is to either click the Accept button next to the most helpful Answer you received, or if none led you near it then write (and Accept) your own Answer.

Comment: okay, got it. edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL query should be:

(subd = 'town1' or subd = 'town3') and village in ('v1','v3','v7','v8')

for only town1 with v1,v3..v8 and town3 with v1,v3..v8.