# How to import label classes to make symbology classes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, labeling, symbology

In Answer to an earlier [Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93840/arcgis-labeling-1-field-with-multiple-selected-value-solved) I was able to write SQL Expressions to create label classes.

Now, I wish to use those label classes to create symbology classes.

It is possible to make label classes from symbology classes, but I want to do it the other way around.

Comment: From what I can see the only difference between this Question and the previous on that you linked to is the last sentence so I recommend that you edit this Question so that it focuses much more on what you mean by "Is it possible to import all the selected value of subd label to symbology?"

Comment: edited, explained more clearly what I want to ask

Comment: It sounds like what you are looking for first is a Symbology equivalent of Label Classes i.e. Symbology Classes defined by SQL Expressions.  For that there is an existing [**ArcGIS Idea**](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008IPaAAM).  In the meantime I think your best bet is to see if you can use ArcPy to create a layer group of layers made from Definition Queries mapped to your Label Class SQL Expressions.

Comment: Hahaha that's correct, thats what I mean, above example just for 3 label (in 1 class) selected using sql expresion, in the reality I have many selected label using sql, It takes realy a long time for me to select the area (again) one by one in symbology.. any solution?